# has_many, belongs_to and comment forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, routes

I'm having two models: `Snippet` and `SnippetComment`. These also have their own controllers, as well as views. In `/app/views/snippets/show.html.erb` I have a form that starts like this:

```
<% form_for(@new_snippet_comment) do |form| %>
```

`SnippetComment` belongs to one `Snippet`, and a `Snippet` belongs to one `User`. This means that I have this routing (`making it non-RESTful == making it suck`, as you know):

```
map.resources :users do |user|
  user.resources :snippets do |snippet|
    snippet.resources :snippet_comments, :as => "comments"
  end
end
```

So when I submit the `SnippetComment` form in the `SnippetController#show` view, this request should be made:

```
POST /users/x/snippets/x/comments HTTP/1.1
```

(where `x` is the `User`'s or `Snippet`'s `id`).

The problem is that I don't even get the comment submission form, but rahter this:

> ## NoMethodError in Snippets#show
>
> Showing
>   app/views/snippets/show.html.erb where
>   line #29 raised:
>
> ```
> undefined method `snippet_comments_path' for
> ```
>
> Extracted source (around line `#29`):
>
> ```
> 26: <% if current_user %>
> 27: <h2>Schrijf een nieuwe reactie</h2>
> 28: 
> 29: <% form_for(@new_snippet_comment) do |form| %>
> 30: 
> 31: <p>
> 32:   <%= form.text_area :body %>
> ```
>
> RAILS_ROOT:
>   /Users/jeffatwood/Dev/youjustdontneedmyrealname
>
> Application Trace | Framework Trace |
>   Full Trace
>
> ```
> /Users/jeffatwood/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/polymorphic_routes.rb:107:in `__send__'
> /Users/jeffatwood/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/polymorphic_routes.rb:107:in `polymorphic_url'
> /Users/jeffatwood/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/polymorphic_routes.rb:114:in `polymorphic_path'
> /Users/jeffatwood/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:298:in `apply_form_for_options!'
> /Users/jeffatwood/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:277:in `form_for'
> /Users/jeffatwood/Dev/youjustdontneedmyrealname/app/views/snippets/show.html.erb:29:in `_run_erb_app47views47snippets47show46html46erb'
> /Users/jeffatwood/Dev/youjustdontneedmyrealname/app/controllers/snippets_controller.rb:19:in `show'
> ```
>
> ### Request
>
> #### Parameters:
>
> ```
> {"id"=>"1",
>  "user_id"=>"2"}
> ```
>
> Show session dump
>
> ### Response
>
> #### Headers:
>
> ```
> {"Content-Type"=>"text/html",
>  "Cache-Control"=>"no-cache"}
> ```

Oh, in `snippets_controller.rb` I have this:

```
def show
  @snippet = Snippet.find(params[:id], :conditions => { :user_id => params[:user_id] })
  @new_snippet_comment = SnippetComment.new

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.xml
    format.json
  end
end
```

Can anyone help me with this problem? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should pass `snipped_id` when you're creating `@new_snippet_comment`

Comment: Where actually? `form_for(@new_snippet_comment, :snippet_id => @snippet.id)`, `form_for(@new_snippet_comment, :url => { :snippet_id => @snippet.id})` (which adds a query string which I don't want) or in the controller?

Comment: `@new_snippet_comment = SnippetComment.new(:snippet_id => 5)` in the controller

Answer (score 0):

You have two levels of nesting ( i.e. user -> snippet -> comment) so your `form_for` syntax should be as follows:

```
form_for [@user, @snippet, @comment]
```